# Using a single index for multiple arrays in a single for loop

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a django project which takes multiple arrays from the view and shows it on a datatable. I can use loop to print a single element properly but can't for the other arrays. Is there any workaround for this issue? The code sample is given below:

```
        <tr>
        <td>  {{x}}  </td>
        <td> <a href="{{link|safe}}">link text</a> </td>
        <td> {{time|safe}} </td>
        <td> {{uploadername|safe}} </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

The view code is below:

```
def publicfiles (request):
    userobj = request.session.get('uid')
    filenamearr = []
    filelinkarr = []
    timearr = []
    uploaderarr = []
    uploadername = [] 
    x = db.child("files").child("public").get()
    print(x.each())
    for user in x.each():
        # dummy data must be skipped that's why if condition
        if (user.val() != 0):
            print (user.key())
            y = db.child("files").child("public").child(user.key()).get()
            userlist = []
            for docs in y.each():
                userlist.append(docs.key())
                userlist.append(docs.val())
            
            filenamearr.append(userlist[0])
            filelinkarr.append(pyrestorage.child(userlist[1]).get_url(None))
            timearr.append(userlist[3])
            uploaderarr.append(userlist[5])
    for user in uploaderarr:
        xyz = db.child("user").child(user).child("name").child("name").get()
        uploadername.append(xyz.val())
    print(uploadername)
    print(userlist)
    print(filenamearr)
    print(filelinkarr)
    print(timearr)
    print(uploaderarr)
    print(type(filenamearr))
    return render(request, 'dashboard/public/datatabledash.html', 
    {'name': filenamearr, 'link': filelinkarr, 'time': timearr, 'uploaderid': uploaderarr, 'uploadername': uploadername})
```

Picture:

[image: Picture of the result of the code]

In the given picture I want the other column elements to show properly like the first column. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Show your view, how do you get these arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the templating system allows you to loop over 2 lists at the same time. So the solution is to create a new variable in your `context` which is the `zip` of the lists.

```py
# In python, you create a new variable and pass it to you view context
custom_array = list(zip(array1, array2))
```

```py
# Then in your html you can loop over the list, which returns 2 items for each iteration
{% for value1, value2 in custom_array %}
    {{ value1 }} is paired with {{ value2 }}
{% endfor %}
```